# I missing all my files and code after git reset --hard

Tags: git, reset

I am missing all my files and code after `git reset --hard` struglled how to get them back,

after I searched in the internet I got this comand `git fsck` then showed this

```
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.    
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)      
notice: No default references
missing tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 
dangling tree 3ab9b3aff07185c0e40931fa038dc087446e1458
dangling blob dafb466e0edcc4c8e165af116aa3f391894e66e4
```

please i can get them back
[This is the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyX3W.png)

Comment: What did you have checked out when you ran that command? What branches/commits existed? Did you run `git reset --hard` exactly, or with some other arguments?

Comment: Did you commit the files before the reset? Try `git branch my-branch -- dafb46` to make a branch at the previous commit.

Comment: There is a command `git reflog` that will have a history of all recent things done, including "lost" commits. While you can use that command directly an easier way to inspect is to use `gitk --reflog`.

Comment: Which command did you run exactly? Please show the full command. Also, are you missing the files or (uncommitted) changes in the files?

Comment: @LeGEC you are right! I wonder if there's a way to reconnect that to a commit?

Answer (score 1):

If u had committed those change before, try

```
git reflog
```